# Hide Page Source Visible in Elastic Beanstalk Application?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I noticed that the source code for my Elastic Beanstalk application is visible after deployment when right-clicking and inspecting the webpage. How do I fix this? I'm having a hard time determining if this is a source code change, build process change, or something else.

I suspect it's a build process thing, but EBS instructs you to deploy a .ZIP of your application without running any kind of *official* build (like `npm run build`, etc.)

FYI - My app is written with ReactJS

Comment: Do you mean that your JavaScript is visible in the browser? You can't do anything about that, sadly. You could minify the script to obfuscate it, but a user could always prettify it again.

Comment: @Tholle Yes, the javascript is visible. Its odd that when using chrome, my source code is in plain sight (right-click > inspect > 'sources' tab), but the source code of other web pages is not.

Comment: The JavaScript is always visible, but you can use something like [UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS) to obfuscate it.